# Why isn't .profile sourced on login to LXDE?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, bash, lubuntu, lxde

I switched recently from GNOME to LXDE and since then my .profile file hasn't been sourced on login. I found out that my PATH variable doesn't include ~/bin anymore. However, my .profile file includes `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` while PATH's content is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`.

Is it intended that LXDE doesn't read this file on login? If yes, what file should I use to add the bin folder to the PATH variable? If not, to what package should I report a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think that there is any requirement/standard for Desktop Environments to execute .profile at startup.  All freedesktop compliant desktops will check for .desktop files in /etc/xdg/autostart and ~/.config/autostart. If you only need ~/bin in PATH when using terminal then use ~/.bashrc.